# Understanding the GPU processes running on my system

Tags: gpu, xorg, fan

running nvidia-smi gave me the following:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxcbE.png)

I am unable to understand what ....AAAA.. process is. How can I know about it, and kill it in case if it is not necessary. Also the Xorg, is it necessary or can I kill it speed up my GPU.
Because I am running tensor flow codes which take up lot of memory.

How can I check whether there is any option of fan, like the ones present in Acer-Predator which increases the performance of the laptop by increasing the fan-speed(pardon me in case of the wrong terminology) or in general is there any way I can speed up my GPU so that my codes run faster.

The reason I want to ask is because when I run the code on GPU, average epoch time is 16 seconds while on CPU it is 21 seconds. This doesn't look significant enough.

When running the code on CPU without GPU, running nvidia-smi gives:
[output#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj4rl.png) 
Would be grateful for any help

Comment: Is this the right place for this question, if not can anyone tell where I can ask

Comment: Given that this involves linux-specific implementations of the GPU's features [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be more likely to have knowledgeable people. You are never "only running code on the CPU" in a modern OS as the interface itself uses the GPU for many tasks. Also the `...` ellipsis means it's only showing the last part of the command used to execute the process. Finally, you can use that last part of the command to find the full command by using `ps aux | grep 'gAAAAAAAAA'` as the process should show up there too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, running the command gave me the output /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle.....     Does this refer to the web browser?

Comment: Looks like it. Yes. Modern Browsers also leverage the GPU for some rendering tasks and video playback.